# Map() function returning as undefined when attempting to return query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, jsx, apollo

I'm having issues returning data from a simple query. I properly executed this with Apollo's test application (https://codesandbox.io/s/nn9y2wzyw4), but when I attempt it with data from my local server it is throwing me a TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. The query is showing up in my console log and on the GraphQL playground.

The only way to return data I have found so far is the map function, but I realize it may not be applicable in this situation. I have tried formatting my return statement a million ways but do not seem to get it. I understand it is likely a very simple solution.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";
import { ApolloProvider, useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql"
});

function GetPokemon() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(gql`
    {
      pokemonById(id: "003") {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  `);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

  console.log(data);

  return data.pokemonById.map((id, name) => (
    <div key={id}>
      <p>
        {id}: {name}
      </p>
    </div>
  ));
}

export const App = () => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <div>
      <h2>My first Apollo app </h2>
      <GetPokemon />
    </div>
  </ApolloProvider>
);
```

For more context, I am using a local version of this GraphQL server: https://github.com/axelhzf/graphql-pokemon-server

And in the playground, my query appears as the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "pokemonById": {
      "id": "003",
      "name": "Venusaur"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use map on an object.

```
  return  (
    <div key={id}>
      <p>
        {data.pokemonById.id}: {data.pokemonById.name}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Ahhh of course. Knew it was stupid simple. Thank you.

Comment: Happens to everyone haha. Just needs some fresh eyes at times.